# Why does classifier chain ask for at least 2 classes, when I have it

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, multilabel-classification

I'm using Classifier Chain with logistic regression and when i try to use fit, i get

> This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the
>   data contains only one class: 1

but I'm pretty sure I have two classes in my data, this is my `X_test`

```
<5825x2000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 219990 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

and I have this as my `y_train`:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0]])
```

and this is the part I'm trying to run

```
cc_clf = ClassifierChain(LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=1, dual=False, solver='liblinear'))
cc_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
cc_y_pred = cc_clf.predict(X_test)
```

Am i using the classifier chain incorrectly? When I pass in the same data into one vs rest, it works.

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(classifier1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Check whether every column of `y_train` has both 0 and 1?

Comment: ...erm, except that should also break `OneVsRestClassifier`, I think.

Comment: How many classes do you have in the output data? Any reason to use Classifier Chain if you have only 2 classes?

Answer (score 0):

To use ClassifierChain every column of y_train has both 0 and 1. Here is a valid and invalid example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.multioutput  import ClassifierChain
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X_train = np.array([[1], [2]])

# Runs 
y_train = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]) 
cc_clf = ClassifierChain(LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=1, dual=False, solver='liblinear'))
cc_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# ValueError
y_train = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 0]])   
cc_clf = ClassifierChain(LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=1, dual=False, solver='liblinear'))
cc_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```